# Create a bookmarkable URL for a regex?

Tags: regex, url, browser, url-routing

I'm writing a JavaScript web application. I would like to allow users to search a directory by regex, and write their search term to the URL so they can bookmark the results.

For example, to produce a bookmarkable search for states with names starting "A" and ending "a":

```
/states/^A.*a$
```

People should be able to bookmark this URL and get results matching Alaska, Arizona and Alabama.

However, I'm finding that URL-safe characters and regex characters don't play nicely together. For example, when I write `^` to the URL, browsers rewrite it as `%5E`.

Can anyone suggest a better way to create a bookmarkable URL for a regex? I don't need to support every possible regex character: just ASCII plus `$`, `*`, `?`, `^`, and `|`.

Ideally I'd like to avoid a long clunky URL with GET parameters like `/states?init=A&final=a`, but maybe that's the way I need to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are really set on having regex searches "persisted" in URLs, I would simply URL-encode / URL-decode the search string and be done with it.

You can explicitly URl-Encode the search string, and then explicitly decode it when they make the request.

That said, I would strongly encourage you to set the search string as a URL *query parameter* rather than as part of the URL itself. Especially in your case where it's a search, you are *much* better off to have the query string as, well, a query string, rather than the URL. It helps things like SEO, REST-compliance, URL maintainability, etc.

Lastly, there are *other* ways to allow users to bookmark searches as well. If you give each search an ID, and store the actual query in a database for that particular bookmark ID, you can give your users nice urls like `/states/search/bookmark/12345/` that are clean, user-friendly, easily bookmarked, shareable, and, best of all, you can do things with them behind the scenes if you need to. This is great for times when you need to upgrade your search, or want to add more power, etc.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't want to URL encode/decode because it looks ugly. I think perhaps the querystring route is the way to go - it looks like characters in querystrings don't get encoded.

Comment: @Richard - I would _still_ encode the query string because different browsers may behave differently. If URL cleanliness is the goal, abstracting the actual query (like I mentioned at the end) is your best route, since it gives the cleanest URLs and the most flexibility on the server-side.

Comment: I'd also like URLs that are readable and hackable, so I'd like to avoid abstracting the query if possible... Maybe this is a problem with no really good solution.

Comment: _Most_ people (and _many_ developers even) find regexes to be some sort of voodoo black magic anyways, so you may be better off with something other than a regex if your goal is to have hackable URLs. A basic keyword search is what most people expect, and you could throw in a few regex-esq nuggets for your "power users" if your underlying search engine can't handle that in it's keywords out of the box.